# The image does not reappear in its proper place after the timeout

Tags: javascript, html, timeout

the ch image vanishes, but when it reeapears, it goes to the left from the right!

```
function rest()
{
img = document.getElementById('ch');
img.style.position= 'absolute';
img.style.top = '0px';
img.style.left = '0px';
img.style.visibility='hidden';

setTimeout(function(){reappearch()},3000);
}
function reappearch(){
img = document.getElementById('ch');
img.style.visibility='visible';
}
```

how do i do it

Answer (score 0):

You have set left to 0px in rest() and so it is going to left side. If you do not want to display it to left then you'll need add img.style.left = '<>px', e.g. img.style.left='150px' in reappearch() function.

```
function reappearch() {
    img = document.getElementById('ch');
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    img.style.left = '120px';
}
```

Check this fiddle...[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNGme/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `img.style.display` and set this to `"none"`, then you won't need to reposition the image and set the position to absolute:

```
function rest() {
    img = document.getElementById('ch');
    img.style.display = 'none';

    setTimeout(function () {
        reappearch()
    }, 3000);
}

function reappearch() {
    img = document.getElementById('ch');
    img.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Good Luck...